# .jar not doing the same thing that in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, path, rxtx

I created a .jar from my Eclipse app.
So I do Export -> JAR File -> I choose my Package + lib -> Define my Main Class
My program use RxTx lib.

Here is my MainFrame :

```
package Main;

 import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
...

public class MainFrame{

public final static String PathLogo1 = "A:/ICOMSSOFT/IVT             Corporation/BlueSoleil/icon-logo.png";
public final static String PathLogo2 = "A:/ICOMSSOFT/IVT Corporation/BlueSoleil/ICOMS LOGO.jpg";
public final static String PathBlueSoleilIcon = "A:/ICOMSSOFT/IVT Corporation/BlueSoleil/BluetoothImage.png";
protected static final JComboBox<String> JB_ChoixPortCom = null;

static JButton JB_Connect;
static String ChoixPortCom = null;

//**********************************************************************************
//************************ RxTx Variable *******************************************
//**********************************************************************************

static CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;
static Enumeration<?> enumComm;
static SerialPort serialPort;
static OutputStream outputStream;
static InputStream inputStream;
static Boolean SerialPortCheck = false;
static int baudrate = 9600;
static int dataBits = SerialPort.DATABITS_8;
static int stopBits = SerialPort.STOPBITS_1;
static int parity = SerialPort.PARITY_NONE;
JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panelSetup = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JPanel panelCommunication = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
static JComboBox<String> selection = new JComboBox<String>();
JButton open = new JButton("Open");
JButton close = new JButton("Close");
JButton actualise = new JButton("Actualisé");
JButton envoie = new JButton("Message envoie");
JTextField message = new JTextField();
JCheckBox echo = new JCheckBox("Echo");
static JTextArea recoit = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane recoitJScrollPane = new JScrollPane();

//**********************************************************************************
//**********************************************************************************
//**********************************************************************************

public static void FenetrePrincipal()  {

    final JFrame JF_Principal = new JFrame("ICOMSSOFT");
    JF_Principal.setVisible(true);
    JF_Principal.setSize(1000,900);
    JF_Principal.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JF_Principal.setResizable(false);

    JF_Principal.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(PathLogo1)); 

    //******************************************************************************************
    //******************************** JPANEL NORTH ********************************************
    //******************************************************************************************

    JPanel JP_North = new JPanel(); // container du BorderLayout.North

    JP_North.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,150));

    JPanel JP_Logo = new JPanel();  // container du JLabel
    JP_Logo.setBackground(Color.white);

    JLabel JL_Logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(PathLogo2));
    JP_Logo.add(JL_Logo);
    JP_North.add(JP_Logo);
    JP_North.setBackground(Color.white);
    JP_North.setVisible(true);

    //******************************************************************************************
    //******************************** JPANEL Center ********************************************
    //******************************************************************************************

    final JPanel JP_Center = new JPanel();
    JP_Center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,700)); // 900- 600 = 300 left
    JP_Center.setBackground(Color.white);

    final JPanel JP_ChoixConnection = new JPanel();
    JP_ChoixConnection.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choix Connection : "));
    JP_ChoixConnection.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540, 175));
    JP_ChoixConnection.setBackground(Color.white);

    ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon(PathBlueSoleilIcon);
    JButton JB_LaunchBlueSoleil = new JButton(pic);
    JB_LaunchBlueSoleil.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 135));

    JP_ChoixConnection.add(JB_LaunchBlueSoleil);
    JP_Center.add(JP_ChoixConnection);

    //******************************************************************************************
    //******************************** JPANEL South ********************************************
    //******************************************************************************************

    JPanel JP_South = new JPanel();
    JP_South.setBackground(Color.white);
    JP_South.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,50));


    JPanel JP_Bouton = new JPanel();
    JP_Bouton.setBackground(Color.white);

    JButton JB_Quit = new JButton("Quitter");
    JB_Quit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 35));

    JP_South.add(JP_Bouton);

    JP_Bouton.add(JB_Quit);

    JF_Principal.getContentPane().add(JP_North, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JF_Principal.getContentPane().add(JP_Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JF_Principal.getContentPane().add(JP_South, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JF_Principal.setVisible(true);

    //******************************************************************************************
    //******************************** Action Listener *****************************************
    //******************************************************************************************

    JB_LaunchBlueSoleil.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try {
                Bluetooth.Launch(Bluetooth.GetPath());              
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String[] ListPortCom = rxtx.GetPortCom();

            int nbrPort = Integer.parseInt(ListPortCom[99]);    // String -> int

            final JPanel JP_ChoixPortCom = new JPanel();
            JP_ChoixPortCom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Choix Port Com : "));
            JP_ChoixPortCom.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
            JP_ChoixPortCom.setBackground(Color.white);


            final JComboBox<String> JB_ChoixPortCom = new JComboBox<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < nbrPort; i++) JB_ChoixPortCom.addItem(ListPortCom[i]);

            JB_Connect = new JButton("Connect");

            JP_ChoixPortCom.add(JB_ChoixPortCom);
            JP_ChoixPortCom.add(JB_Connect);

            JP_Center.add(JP_ChoixPortCom);

            System.out.println("JP_ChoixConnection -> bye bye");
            JP_ChoixConnection.setVisible(false);
            CommunicationBT.BT(JP_Center);

            JB_ChoixPortCom.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                ChoixPortCom = (String)JB_ChoixPortCom.getSelectedItem();           
            }});

            JB_Connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                    if (ChoixPortCom.equals(null) == true ) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose Port COM");
                    else rxtx.CheckPort(ChoixPortCom);
                }      
            });

        }      
    });

    JB_Quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JF_Principal.dispose();
        }      
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FenetrePrincipal();
}
```

}

And here is where I call the GetPortCom :

```
package Main;
import gnu.io.*; // RXTX

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class rxtx {

static CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;
static Enumeration<?> enumComm;
static SerialPort serialPort;
static OutputStream outputStream;
static InputStream inputStream;

int baudrate = 9600;
int dataBits = SerialPort.DATABITS_8;
int stopBits = SerialPort.STOPBITS_1;
int parity = SerialPort.PARITY_NONE;

static Boolean SerialPortCheck = false;

public static String[] GetPortCom(){
    String[] List = new String[100]; // List[99] = nbrPort
    int nbrPort = 0;

    CommPortIdentifier serialPortId;
    Enumeration<?> enumComm; 

    enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (enumComm.hasMoreElements()) {
        serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
        if(serialPortId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            //System.out.println(serialPortId.getName());
            List[nbrPort] = serialPortId.getName();
            nbrPort++;
        }

        List[99] = Integer.toString(nbrPort);   // Int -> String

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nbrPort; i++) {
        System.out.println(List[i]);
    }

    return List;
}

public static boolean CheckPort(String portName){

    boolean foundPort = false;
    if (SerialPortCheck != false) {
        System.out.println("Serial Port déjà ouvert");
        return true;
    }
    enumComm = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while(enumComm.hasMoreElements()) {
        serialPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) enumComm.nextElement();
        if (portName.contentEquals(serialPortId.getName())) {
            foundPort = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (foundPort != true) {
        System.out.println("Serialport pas trouver: " + portName);
        return false;
    }
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) serialPortId.open("Ouvert + Envoie", 500);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println("Port -> OK");
    }
    try {
        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Probleme en OutputStream");
    }
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Probleme en InputStream");
    }
    SerialPortCheck = true;
    return true;
}
```

The thing that I don't understand is why it works perfectly in Eclipse but not with the jar, all the path are correct so I don't get it :/

More information :

So this app call another program(BlueSoleil) when you click on the button.
My problem with the .jar, when I click on the button the program launchs correctly but it block there the rest doesn't appear. It is suppose to change my JP_Center (JPanel) by switching with an another JPanel -> launch getPortCom and then create an JCombobox with all the PortCom available.

Comment: Which paths? What happens precisely?

Comment: I add more information up